# Coalescing Azure Data Factory activity outputs

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

**TL;DR:**
My output value is not null, but does not exists, and there for coalesce does not work.

Curious if anyone has found away to coalesce output arguments for activities. I know there is an actual expression "Coalesce" but that does not do what I would like.

When an activity runs, it returns the general response json with items like PipelineName, RunID, Status and Error. When Status is "Succeeded" error is "Null", and when status is "Failed" error is another json of things like "failureType", "message" and "statuscode". For the scope of my problem I would like to log Error.message, when the value exists. So basically I have a generic pipeline for logging, and I would pass parameters to log, such as
`@activity('Execute Pipeline1')[0].Status` or `@activity('Execute Pipeline1')[0].Error.message`.

However when I map like such, when successful, Error.message does not exist. My options look like either creating a "run on success" and "run on failure" execution of the pipeline, or just logging the Error json.

Does anyone know of any expressional way to coalesce these values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems [Contains](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions#contains) function can help you. You can try something like this expression:

```
@if(contains(activity('Execute Pipeline1')[0],'Error'),activity('Execute Pipeline1')[0].Error.message,'no error')
```

If you only want to log information when activity fails, you can create a If Condition activity. Then use this `contains(activity('Execute Pipeline1')[0],'Error')` to check whether it fails and log error message in case True.

Comment: Ah perfect, let me try that this afternoon.

Comment: This is almost the answer. When implementing this the contains fails when activity.Error is NULL. Since it expects a dictionary. But I think this is the right path.

Comment: To be more specific, the above statement "cannot be evaluated because property 'message' cannot be selected."

Comment: The answer is "@if(empty(activity('Execute Pipeline1').Error), '', activity('Execute Pipeline1').Error.message)". The [0] is dependent on what you are evaluating.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that you got the right answer. Congratulation!